# Capitalization of App

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I'm trying to write a promotional piece on our new app. I can't figure out how to capitalize in these two instances (not in a title). My gut tells me lowercase but other team members have been using capital A. What's the reasoning behind the correct answer?

Welcome to the new XYZ App/app.
Our App/app has many new features.

Answer (score 7):

Whether to capitalize the first case depends on whether you consider *app* to be part of the title of the product.  If you call your program *XYZ App*, as opposed to *XYZ*, then *App* would be correct.  Otherwise, if your product is simply titled *XYZ*, then *app* is appropriate.

In the second case, *app* is preferred.  The word *app* is short for *application*, so it would be weird in most contexts to capitalize it.  (Exceptions exist, as always.)